# Two lists are printing the same thing when I expected them to print differently

Tags: python, list

I have a list `a=[[1]]` and `b=[i for i in a]`. Now i do `b[0].append(2)`. When I print `a` and `b`, they are the same `[[1, 2]]` and `[[1, 2]]`. Looks like the list `b[0]` is referencing to the same one in a. Why does this happen?

```
a=[[1]]
b=[i for i in a]
b[0].append(2)
print a,b
```

Output: `[[1, 2]] [[1, 2]]`

Comment: Can you include the code you are using

Comment: what does  'print a is b' yeild. I believe your creation of b is just referencing that of a's elements, thus also updating them. There is a reason, bit I can't for the likes of me remember what it was, sorry.

Comment: So in order to make a completely new copy of list a, I would have to go in, get the elements, make new list and populate the new list?

Comment: a list don't contain the object themselves but a reference to that object, in your case when you copy the elements `a` of in `b` you copy say references, when you do the append python put that element in list reference by it, that is why you see the change in both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` and `b` are different lists. But `a[0]` is the same list as `b[0]`, because you didn't make a copy of it when you constructed `b`; the two lists contain references to the same sublists. You can make a copy of the sublist with:

```
b = [i[:] for i in a]
```

See [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python) for other ways to copy a list.

If you want to copy all levels at once, you can use `copy.deepcopy()`

```
import copy
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```